# Power function inequality

Tags: tag-removed, real-analysis, inequalities

Let $x$ and $p$ be real numbers with $x \ge 1$ and $p \ge 2$ . Show that $(x - 1)(x + 1)^{p - 1} \ge x^p - 1$ .

I recently discovered this result. I am sure it is known, but it is new to me. It is quite easy to prove if $p$ is an integer, even a negative one. I have a proof in the general case above, but it seems overly complicated. Can someone provide a simple demonstration?

Comment: I like the phrasing of your question; it suggests curiosity, politeness, and the desire to learn.  Unfortunately, there is lack of motivation, and I can't tell if we are being asked to solve a homework problem.  I recommend asking this on math.stackexchange, with motivation provided.  Also, I suspect this question is outside the scope of this forum.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.19

Comment: @Gerhard: According to the OP's profile, and, as corroborated by the math genealogy database, it seems highly unlikely this is a homework question. :) (That said, I agree it's still off-topic.)

Comment: Also, this question has already appeared on math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71758/power-function-inequality

Comment: @Richard: I have posted an answer to the math.SE version. I'm not sure if you were expecting something simpler than that. Cheers.

Comment: If the poster had added what method he used to show it, or what he was going to do with the result, it would be a more appropriate question for MathOverflow.  If my advisor or Terry Tao or gowers or anyone else had posted the same question with the same wording, I would still ask for motivation and remark that it looked like a homework question to me.  That said, I agree it is a nice problem and hope a good answer is forthcoming on some forum.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.19

Comment: @Gerhard: I was not intending to be snarky with my comment. I hope you did not take it as such and, if that was the tone that came across, my apologies. Cheers. 

Comment: No offense taken, cardinal.  As long as you understand my point, you are even welcome to disagree with it.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.19

Comment: I wanted to explain that I noticed this result while studying an argument of Mazur's that Lp is homeomorphic to L1 for 1 < p < oo. It went unanswered for a week on math.stackexchange before I posted it here.

Comment: Richard Hevener, if you had led with some detail about the Mazur argument and the waiting time on math.stackexchange, it probably would have shut me up.  Welcome to MathOverflow.  Some of us here really like motivating remarks.  Gerhard "My Mouth Is Size Ten" Paseman, 2011.10.20

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We prove strict inequality for $x>1$ and $p>2$.  Add $1$ to both sides and divide by $x^p$ to get an equivalent inequality that can be written as 
$$
\frac{x-1}{x} \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^{p-1} + \frac1x \left( \frac1x \right)^{p-1} \geq 1.
$$
Since $p > 2$ the function $f : X \mapsto X^{p-1}$ is strictly convex upwards.  The left-hand side is a weighted average
$$
\frac{x-1}{x} f\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right) + \frac1x f\left( \frac1x \right)
$$
of values of $f$, with positive weights and evaluated at different $X$'s.  Hence by [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) it strictly exceeds the value of $f$ at the corresponding weighted average of $X$'s, which is
$$
f\left(\frac{x-1}{x} \cdot \frac{x+1}{x} + \frac1x \cdot \frac1x \right) = f(1) = 1,
$$
**QED**.

The same argument shows that the inequality holds for $p<1$, and is reversed for $1 < p < 2$ because then $f$ is concave downwards.

Comment: Very nice! I wonder how robust is this approach in general.

Comment: @Seva: Thanks!  What do you mean by "robust" in this context?

Comment: I mean something of the following sort: given a "random inequality", what are the chances that it can be proved by applying Jensen's inequality to an appropriately selected function. Pretty high, I guess...

Comment: Beautiful argument--thanks.  As cardinal observed over at math.stackexchange, you don't need Jensen, just convexity.

Comment: @Seva: what probability measure are you using to select a "random inequality"? ;-)  Jensen / convexity is a versatile tool for proving inequalities of mathematical interest; the application here feels somewhat unusual but I'm sure it's not the strangest use I've seen of the technique.

Answer (score 0):

Since the case $x=1$ is trivial, assume $x>1$ and divide both sides by $x-1$. It becomes
$$(x+1)^{p-1}\ge \frac{x^p-1}{x-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{p-1}.$$
Expand the left side by the binomial theorem and compare it with the right side.

Comment: As Richard observed, the case when p is integral is easily done.  Can you provide something almost as nice for nonintegral p?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.20

Comment: Yeah, I realised that after posting. Oops.

Comment: If you started this way with rational p (and perhaps letting x=y^(pq) for a suitable integer pq), you might redeem the approach, introduce some cool combinatorics, extend the result to real p by continuity, and provide an extension to the result in a fashion similar to what Noam Elkies did.  I would do it myself, but after rewriting I get (y^r +1)^(pq) >= something to the power r which needs more cool combinatorics to handle than I can muster currently.  Gerhard "The Buck Passes Here, Sometimes" Paseman, 2011.10.23